# How to customize filter on fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, php, calendar

Is there a way to customize a filter on full calendar? For example, I want to be able to jump to a specific month or year without clicking the arrow keys to make it friendlier unlike clicking which takes too much time. If there is - how do I go about customizing it or what code is required?

e.g:

> Current Month is Sep and I want to go to Dec
>
> Current Year 2019 but I want to go to 2020 or higher

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/gotoDate

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function "gotoDate"

```
calendar.gotoDate('2020-12-1');
```

like this :

```
<button id="btn">go to dec 2020</button>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        titleFormat: {year: 'numeric'},
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'moment', 'momentTimezone'],
        header:{
            left: '',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'prevYear,nextYear'
        }   
    });

    calendar.render();

    // go to dec 2020
    $('#btn').click(function() {
        calendar.gotoDate('2020-12-1');
    });

});
```

Think to initialize "moment" library before the fullCalendar plugins

Comment: Code is always good, but it also helps to add some comments or context around how this code solves the original question.